# Set bitrate on VideCapture useCase camerax

Tags: android, kotlin, video-capture, android-camerax

I want to capture an image and video from the camera of the application and send it to server. Thus i use CameraX library which provides easily implemented use cases for image capture and video capture.
However, i want to set some parameters of the video recording. I want to set the bitrate, (width, height) and fps of the video recording.

What i do is

```
videoCapture = VideoCapture.Builder()
            .setVideoFrameRate(30)
            .setBitRate(480000)
            .setAudioBitRate(70000)
            .setAudioChannelCount(1)
            .build()

cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, videoCapture)
```

However, after recording the video i put it to a Media file analyzer and i see that the bitrate is totally different from the one that i set.

[image]

Why is this happening? How can i record a video with the characteristics that i want??

Comment: Did you figure this out?

I can't see where your getting "setBitRate" from in the docs either

Comment: Facing the same issue and I'm also unable to find `setBitRate` - @james04 can you elaborate? Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didnt figure it out guys. but i remember that i switched to Camera2 API which is older but more flexible